# Communication between windows using javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for how to communicate two differents windows with Javascript, but I haven't found anything usefull...

The thing is:

Imagine that I have a Web Page which have some data and another web page is required to do something, I want to send information from the first one to the second one, process that data in the second one and get back a result to the original web page.

I don't know if I do make myself clear, first of all because I'm English learner, but if you can help I really appreciate that.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one window is opening up the other window then you can have them pass data via function calls.  The calling window can save the window variable and then call methods on that window.  The called window can also make function calls on the parent window that opened it.

```
//the parent window must open the child window for this to work
<script>
var childWindow = null;  //page level variable for the child window

function OpenChildWindow() {
    childWindow = window.open(URL);  //create the child window and save the window to our variable
}

function SendChildData(data) {
    childWindow.XferData(data);  //this calls the function on the child window
}

function ReceiveChildData(data) {
    //do something with the data from the child window
}
</script>

//from the child window you can send or receive data as well
//the parent window is accessable via the opener property.
<script>
function SendParentData(data) {
  opener.ReceiveChildData(data)  //this calls the javascript function on the parent window and send it the data
}

function XferData(data) {
    //this receives data from the parent window
}
</script>
```

Comment: But It works even when the second page isn't in the same server?

Comment: i have not tried that but i think it will still work.  its very simple to test it out.  Just put a function in the parent that shows an alert and then when the child window opens up you can call that function.  only takes a minute to setup

Comment: I actually did it using 2 different web sites and it does work.  Are you using IE?  It may be browser dependent so that may be a deal breaker for you

Comment: But can you send information between those webs? I’m using Chrome

Comment: Yes I do.  Its a javascript function call so you can add any parameters you want and send anything when you call the function.

Comment: i edited the main answer with all the code to explain the process.  this is all done client side so you will need to plug in the events that fire off the functions.  Hopefully this will give you a good starting point on how to pass data back and forth

Comment: When I tried to do that, I literally copy and paste your code, and the console show me this: Uncaught TypeError: childWindow.XferData is not a function
    at SendChildData (main.js:54)
    at OpenChildWindow (main.js:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):17)

Comment: How are you opening up the 2 windows?    Is there a third window doing it or is there only 2?  It sounds like your pages are not tied together properly

Comment: I’ve been trying another methods but there is the thing GitHub.com/caphyr/vippopaymentbutton and GitHub.com/caphyr/prueba